# High memory usage with multiple Oracle connections in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a WorkerService .NET app running on Linux, which purpose is just to connect to an Oracle database to check if the password is still valid.

There is no data retrieval, only connect and disconnect in parallel with a number of 22 Oracle accounts.

I am using the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core`  library.

The problem is that I am experiencing high memory usage and because of this I've collected a memory dump which looks like this:

[image]

Even if pooling is disabled I still see some connection pooling objects still referenced.

This is how GC looks like:

[image]

This is a self-contained .NET6 WorkerService app, which uses approx. 5GB RAM with Oracle connection checking disabled and jumps to approx. 9GB RAM when ORA connections are being initialized.

The way I am creating the connections is by using this static class:

```
public static class ConnectionManager
{
    public static async Task<IDbConnection> GetConnectionAsync(ServerConnectionDetails connectionDetails,
                                                               CancellationToken cancellationToken = default,
                                                               bool pooling = false)
    {
        var connectionBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            DataSource = connectionDetails.Name,
            UserID = connectionDetails.Username,
            Password = connectionDetails.Password,
            Pooling = pooling,
            ConnectionTimeout = 120
        };

        var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionBuilder.ToString());
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static void CloseConnection(IDbConnection conn)
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        if (conn is not null)
        {
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Checking if the password is still valid is by calling this method:

```
public abstract class OracleDatabaseRepositoryBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<OracleDatabaseRepositoryBase> _logger;

    protected OracleDatabaseRepositoryBase(ILogger<OracleDatabaseRepositoryBase> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task TestDataBaseConnectionAsync(ServerConnectionDetails connectionDetails, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {

        using IDbConnection connection = await ConnectionManager.GetConnectionAsync(connectionDetails, cancellationToken);
        _logger.LogDebug("Successfully connected to Oracle database with {Account} account.", connectionDetails.Username);
        ConnectionManager.CloseConnection(connection);
    }

}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't disposing of your `conn` object if `OpenAsync` throws an exception. You'll need a `try/catch+throw` for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000

Comment: When you do `new OracleConnection(...)`, it's not going to be open so testing the `State` property immediately is superfluous.

Comment: Your `CloseConnection` method is entirely unnecessary. `IDbConnection.Close()` always does the _exact same thing_ as `.Dispose()` does (though I agree the documentation is unclear).

Comment: Yeah, that too... so much cruft. It's pure noise.

Comment: I've updated the post with the method that does the connection dispose.

Comment: @Dai Understood, I can ditch the CloseConnection() method and just use `IDbConnection.Close()` or probably it gets closed by just having the `using` keyword.

Comment: Per Dai's comment, the entirety of `CloseConnection` is unnecessary. `using` will close the connection as part of disposal. Don't just remove the call to that method. Actually remove the method from your code, period. You should get errors where you're now callling a method that doesn't exist. Now remove all the calls to fix the errors.

Comment: @madreflection Did that, but I don't think this is the cause of the memory usage.

Comment: Maybe not, but you will have removed a bunch of junk. If you are, as you claim, doing all 22 connections in parallel, that could be a problem.

Comment: What exactly is your quantification of "high memory usage", and what are you expecting to be different? All you've provided is a screenshot.

Comment: This is a self-contained .NET 6 WorkerService which, if not doing Oracle connection checks, uses aprox. 5 GB RAM, after I enable the Oracle connection checking the RAM usage jumps to aprox. 8GB when connections start being initiated and after that just stays like this.

Comment: That memory is likely due to support libraries lazy-loaded by Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

Comment: @madreflection I am not sure about that, I've tested with just one account and the memory is increasing with only 1GB, so there is something happening for every account that is being added for connection testing.

Comment: @Mihaimyh The profiler screenshot you've posted only shows Oracle's client-library using around **40 MiB** - that's a far cry from the gigabytes of memory you say it's leaking. Also, how many CPU cores do you have? .NET will gladly claim 100MB+ of RAM _per core_  so it can give each GC thread its own hardware-thread-specific buffers - unfortunately I don't know how to disable that.

Comment: @Dai The server has 32 CPU cores

Comment: @Mihaimyh That's likely the issue then: you're misinterpreting the RAM allocated to .NET's per-hardware-thread GC system.

Comment: @Dai I will investigate this, thanks for the tip. One question: why does the memory increases that much only when I am enabling Oracle connections checking? Is it because GC has a lot more work to be done cleaning after the Oracle resources?

Comment: @Mihaimyh I don't know - I don't have any experience with Oracle's client libraries.